# Existe alguma técnica para sincronização de uma estrutura de um banco de dados SQL Server?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, sincronização

Tive alguns problemas recentemente ao fazer modificações no ambiente de homologação e por questões burocráticas essas modificações não puderam ser inspecionadas no ambiente de produção e foram feitas de forma errada, causando uma demora na identificação do problema.

Pra evitar isso gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma ideal de proceder nesses casos. No caso específico do SQL Server, se é possível criar uma query que possa comparar dois bancos e realizar a remoção, adição e/ou modificação de campos e tabelas.

Nesse caso eu apenas passaria a query para o responsável pela manutenção do BD e ele rodaria, evitando erros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe sim. É [a comparação de Schemas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272690(v=vs.103).aspx), dentro do [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh297027.aspx).

Comment: Essa ferramenta gera a query de atualização ou faz o trabalho através de interações com cliques?

Comment: Já achei aqui, obrigado: Click the Generate Script button (the fourth one from the left) on the toolbar for the Schema Compare window.

Comment: Dá pra fazer por script também, caso seja necessário, mas se você tem acesso aos dois databases sem restrições, dá pra fazer tudo pelo modo gráfico.

Comment: Não sei se faço outra pergunta, o que você acha? Eu gostaria de saber isso também para databases do Oracle.

Comment: Sim, melhor outra, pra manter a consistência de Tags.

Comment: No Oracle acho que o Sql Developer faz ....  http://blog.devart.com/comparing-two-oracle-schemas-is-simple-now.html